# XSLT question - Transpose multiple columns to rows

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an xml that needs one row (report_entry) split into multiple columns. The columns starting from `wd:W2_401k through` `wd:W2_Uncollected_Social_Security_Tax_Tips`need to be split into 17 columns. The approach I know is to use a for-each wd:report_entry, use 17 templates and define common fields repetitively. Is there an efficient way to do this? I have posted my xslt for 3 row split, need to it for 17 rows though.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/ERP-PAY-CR_PAYROLL_BALANCES_SUMMARY_W2">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Country>US</wd:Country>
        <wd:Entity_Name>BalanceInitialization</wd:Entity_Name>
        <wd:Legislative_Data>US Care LDG</wd:Legislative_Data>
        <wd:Legal_Entity_Name>Wayne Industries</wd:Legal_Entity_Name>
        <wd:Person_Number>2188941</wd:Person_Number>
        <wd:Effective_As_of_Date>2020-01-01</wd:Effective_As_of_Date>
        <wd:Assignment_Number>2188946-04272015E01</wd:Assignment_Number>
        <wd:W2_401k>7062.6</wd:W2_401k>
        <wd:W2_Roth_401k>0</wd:W2_Roth_401k>
        <wd:W2_457>0</wd:W2_457>
        <wd:W2_Health_Saving_Account>0</wd:W2_Health_Saving_Account>
        <wd:W2_BOX_14A_-_CASDI>1229.09</wd:W2_BOX_14A_-_CASDI>
        <wd:W2_BOX_14B_-_FOUND>0</wd:W2_BOX_14B_-_FOUND>
        <wd:W2_BOX_14C_-_UWAY>0</wd:W2_BOX_14C_-_UWAY>
        <wd:W2_BOX_14D_-_TRANSP>0</wd:W2_BOX_14D_-_TRANSP>
        <wd:W2_BOX_14E_-_UNION_DUE>0</wd:W2_BOX_14E_-_UNION_DUE>
        <wd:W2_BOX_14F_-_HCRA>1000</wd:W2_BOX_14F_-_HCRA>
        <wd:W2_BOX_14G_-_EMPCMPGN>125</wd:W2_BOX_14G_-_EMPCMPGN>
        <wd:W2_Dependent_Care>0</wd:W2_Dependent_Care>
        <wd:W2_Group_Term_Life>0</wd:W2_Group_Term_Life>
        <wd:W2_Health_Coverage>6970</wd:W2_Health_Coverage>
        <wd:W2_Qualified_Move>0</wd:W2_Qualified_Move>
        <wd:W2_Uncollected_Medicare_Tips>0</wd:W2_Uncollected_Medicare_Tips>
        <wd:W2_Uncollected_Social_Security_Tax_Tips>0</wd:W2_Uncollected_Social_Security_Tax_Tips>
        <wd:Upload_Date>2020-01-01</wd:Upload_Date>
        <wd:Dimension>Relationship Tax Unit Year To Date</wd:Dimension>
        <wd:PR_Relationship>2188946</wd:PR_Relationship>
        <wd:Legal_Employer>St. Joseph Health System</wd:Legal_Employer>
        <wd:Payroll wd:Descriptor="Biweekly A">
            <wd:ID wd:type="WID">2af036de57bc01be1ff6752d9a18f5c6</wd:ID>
            <wd:ID wd:type="Evaluate_Expression_Band_Related_Content_Reference_ID">EVALUATE_EXPRESSION_BAND_CALCULATED_FIELD_RELATED_CONTENT-6-505</wd:ID>
        </wd:Payroll>
        <wd:Tax_Reporting_Unit>Wayne Corporation</wd:Tax_Reporting_Unit>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

Xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/ERP-PAY-CR_PAYROLL_BALANCES_SUMMARY_W2">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    
    <xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pipe" select="'|'"/>
    <xsl:param name="quote">"</xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:template match="/wd:Report_Data">
        
        <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
            
            
            <xsl:call-template name="W2_401k">
                
            </xsl:call-template>
            
            <xsl:call-template name="W2_Roth_401k">
                
            </xsl:call-template>
            
            <xsl:call-template name="W2_457">
                
            </xsl:call-template>
            
        </xsl:for-each>
        
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="W2_401k">
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Country"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Entity_Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Legislative_Data"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Legal_Entity_Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Person_Number"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Effective_As_of_Date"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Assignment_Number"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(wd:W2_401k,'#.00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <!-- Upload Date Place Holder -->
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Upload_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Dimension"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Person_Number"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Payroll/@wd:Descriptor"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Area_One"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <!-- Balance Date Place Holder -->
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Effective_As_of_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Tax_Reporting_Unit"/>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="W2_Roth_401k">
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Country"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Entity_Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Legislative_Data"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Legal_Entity_Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Person_Number"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Effective_As_of_Date"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Assignment_Number"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(wd:W2_Roth_401k,'#.00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <!-- Upload Date Place Holder -->
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Effective_As_of_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Dimension"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Person_Number"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Payroll/@wd:Descriptor"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Area_One"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <!-- Balance Date Place Holder -->
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Effective_As_of_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Tax_Reporting_Unit"/>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="W2_457">
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Country"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Entity_Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Legislative_Data"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Legal_Entity_Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Person_Number"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Effective_As_of_Date"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Assignment_Number"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(wd:W2_457,'#.00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <!-- Upload Date Place Holder -->
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Effective_As_of_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
     
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Dimension"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Person_Number"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Payroll/@wd:Descriptor"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Area_One"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <!-- Balance Date Place Holder -->
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Effective_As_of_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:Tax_Reporting_Unit"/>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would at least try to shorten the code like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/ERP-PAY-CR_PAYROLL_BALANCES_SUMMARY_W2"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.workday.report/ERP-PAY-CR_PAYROLL_BALANCES_SUMMARY_W2">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:param name="linefeed" select="'&#xD;&#xA;'"/>
    
    <xsl:param name="pipe" select="'|'"/>
    
    <xsl:param name="quote">"</xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry">
        <xsl:variable name="entry" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="W2_401k, W2_Roth_401k, W2_457">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$entry" mode="transpose">
                <xsl:with-param name="col" select="."/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry" mode="transpose">
        <xsl:param name="col"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Country"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Entity_Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Legislative_Data"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Legal_Entity_Name"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Person_Number"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Effective_As_of_Date"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Assignment_Number"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($col,'#.00')"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$pipe"/>
        
        <!-- Upload Date Place Holder -->
        <xsl:value-of select="Upload_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Dimension"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Person_Number"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Payroll/@wd:Descriptor"/>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Area_One"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <!-- Balance Date Place Holder -->
        <xsl:value-of select="Effective_As_of_Date"/>
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:value-of select="Tax_Reporting_Unit"/>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        
        <xsl:text>|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And XSLT 2.0 has an `xsl:value-of select="sequence-expression" separator="{$pipe}"` that might help to reduce the verbosity of all your separate `xsl:value-of`, `xsl:value-of select="$pipe"` but I haven't tried to identify which "empty" cols you want or need to spell that out exactly, but along  the lines of

```
<xsl:template match="Report_Entry" mode="transpose">
    <xsl:param name="col"/>
    
    <xsl:value-of 
      select="Country, Entity_Name, Legislative_Data, Legal_Entity_Name, Person_Number,
              Effective_As_of_Date, Assignment_Number, 
              format-number($col,'#.00'),
              Upload_Date, 
              '', '', 
              Dimension, PersonNumber,
              '', '', '', '',
              Payroll/@wd:Descriptor, Area_One,
              '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
              Effective_As_of_Date, Tax_Reporting_Unit,
              (1 to 10) ! ''" 
              separator="{$pipe}"/>
    
    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked great. I am trying to apply a filter to suppress any rows where the amount is 0. So in the above example, I only need one row as W2_Roth_401k and W2_457 is zero.
        <wd:W2_401k>7062.6</wd:W2_401k>
        <wd:W2_Roth_401k>0</wd:W2_Roth_401k>
        <wd:W2_457>0</wd:W2_457>

Comment: Use a predicate `<xsl:for-each select="(W2_401k, W2_Roth_401k, W2_457)[. != 0]">`.

Comment: Again, it worked :) One last thing - I need to add another data element (column) that will show the header i.e.,
W2_401k 
W2_Roth_401k
W2_457
I tried using value-of select="name()" but that returns wd:Report_Entry. Can you please help?

Comment: `name($col)` is probably what you want to output.

Comment: Thank you! name($col) returns `wd:W2_401k` but I need `W2_401k`

Comment: Then use `local-name($col)`, no?